# How to prove the existence of upper truncated point?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, weibull-distribution

Currently I am working on a data-set seems to have a Weibull distribution. Problem is that not sure if Weibull or Truncated-Weibull is better to use. Any methods or Hypothesis test there to prove if upper truncated point exist or not? If yes, how to determine it statistically? Is that fine just use the Largest Observation as the upper truncated point?

Comment: In general I believe that maximum likelihood estimation of the upper bound will *always* give you the observed maximum as the best estimate (this is related to the [German tank problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) and [this Math SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411145/maximum-likelihood-estimation-of-a-b-for-a-uniform-distribution-on-a-b)). Furthermore, the likelihood will always be higher for the truncated Weibull. I'm not sure whether the assumptions of the likelihood ratio test are met or not, though ...